# Trying to display a paragraph when selecting in a list and also be able to add one.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paragraph

I would like to be able to select a option and have a certain paragraph be displayed in the div above but it is not showing. The add paragraph button that opens up the div and allows you to add the option in but not the paragraph itself.Also the delete button works fine as well. I am using basic java script.

When the values like z.sen1 to z.sen3 are selected i would like it to display the sentences in them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DreStone.css">
  <style> 
    div#addPara {display: none;} 
    .clrb {clear: both;} 
  </style> 
 <title> Simple story </title>




     <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
<script src="util.js"></script>

<script> 
var z={}; 


//****************************

z.init = function()
{
u.eid("sel").selectIndex = 0;
z.showPara(u.eid("sel").value);
} 

//**************************************
z.showPara=function(fileName)
{
u.eid("story").src = fileName;
} 


//*************************************

z.selectpara = function()
{
z.showPara(u.eid("sel").value); 
}

//***************************************

z.addtext = function()
  { var newOpt = document.createElement("option"); 

  newOpt.text = u.eid("addop").value; 
  newOpt.value = u.eid("addit").value; 
  u.eid("sel").appendChild(newOpt);

  u.eid("addPara").style.display = "none"; 
  } 

  //***************************************

  z.NewPara = function()
  { 
  u.eid("addPara").style.display = "block";

  } 


  z.flipPara = function()
  { var list = u.eid("sel"); 
        z.sen1 = "well ok then i gusse"; 
        z.sen2 = "then you start it";
        z.sen3 = "after that you"; 
  //--- GO TO THE NEXT PICTURE


//--- IF WE'VE GONE BEYOND 4, GO BACK TO 0
list.selectedIndex = (list.selectedIndex + 1) %  list.length;

/*
if ((list.selectedIndex + 1) >= list.length)
   list.selectedIndex = 0;
else
   list.selectedIndex++;
*/

//--- OUTPUT THE CURRENT PICTURE
z.showPara(list.value);
}

  //****************************************

 z.rmPara = function()
 { var ost = u.eid("sel"); 

 if (!confirm("Do you really want to delete this paragraph?"))
   {
   return;
   }
 ost.removeChild(ost.options[ost.selectedIndex]);
 z.showPara(ost.value); 
 } 

z.noAdd = function()
{
u.eid("addPara").style.display = "none"; 
} 
/**********************
WINDOW.ONLOAD
***********************/
window.onload = function()
{
u.eid("story").addEventListener('click', z.flipPara); 
u.eid("sel").addEventListener('change', z.selectpara);
u.eid("addtext").addEventListener('click', z.addtext); 
u.eid("NewPara").addEventListener('click', z.NewPara);
u.eid("noAdd").addEventListener('click', z.noAdd); 
u.eid("rmPara").addEventListener('click', z.rmPara); 

//--- INITIALIZE THE PAGE
z.init();
}
</script> 
</head>

<body>

<h3>Simple story</h3>

<div id="story">
</div> 
<figure>
<img src="C:\Users\Morningside\Pictures\lol.png" height="500" width="700">
<caption>League</caption>
</figure>

  <select id="sel" class="clrb">
   <option value="z.sen1"> Started playing </option>
   <option value="z.sen2"> Him leaving</option>
   <option value="z.sen3"> Me getting better</option>
   <option> He figured it out</option>
   <option> Why I was doing good</option>
  </select> 
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="NewPara" type "button">Add Paragraph</button>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;<button id="rmPara" type="button">Remove Paragraph</button>

  <div id="addPara">
  <hr>
  Add Paragraph: <input id="addit" type="text">
  &nbsp;&nbsp; Option list: <input id="addop" type="text"> 
  <br><br>

  <button id="noAdd" type="button"> 
  Return without Adding</button> 
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button id="addtext" type="button">Add Paragraph</button> 
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should use JQuery.